# Preserve variable type?

Tags: php, variables, types

I have a problem that I need to solve.

I have an associative array, eg:

```
private $formData = [
"lastPrintedNumber" => 0,
];
```

I obtain this data from a text file with a function...:

```
$line = fgets( $formDataFile );
$explodedLine = explode( ' ', $linea );
$this->formData[ 'lastPrintedNumber' ] = (int) $explodedLine[2];
```

It assigns the correct type, `int`, to $formData[ lastPrintdNumber ].

But I don't want to hardcode the assignments, instead I want to do a `foreach`, looking for the right data in the array.

Example:

```
$line = fgets( $formDataFile ) ) != false ) {
$explodedLine = explode( ' ', $linea );
foreach( $this->formDatos as $key => $value ) {
    if( $explodedLine[0] == $key ) {
        $this->formData[ $key ] = $value;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it assigns the value as `string`, and in some case I need `int` for maths.

So I would need a way to stablish the data type for `formData[ 'lastPrintedNumber' ]` to always be `int`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: PHP will autoconvert between string/int as needed. `$x = 7 * '3'` is still `21`, even though it's int * string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small point: You should be using `==` in the `if`, not just `=`.

That aside, it doesn't matter like it does in JavaScript. In JS, if you have `a = "1"; b = "2"; alert(a+b)` you get `12`, but in PHP you get 3 because `+` expects numbers.

PHP's type coercion solves almost all problems by itself, so there's usually no need to specify a certain type.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it *is* a string coming from the text file, there are no "types" in text files. If you want to coerce text values into more appropriate data types, you need to test what type they may be best suited for. You should check whether something is suited to be an `int` using [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) and if so cast it.

Really though, a string works perfectly fine as well for mathematical operations, PHP will cast it to a number automatically when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You know if you wanted to convert a string value thats a number, into a number variable use

```
intval($myvar);
```